# what is the word close to but not stronger than 'spiky'

Tags: single-word-requests

a) For a sequence 1,2,1,2,1,1,1,2,2 we can say it is '***uniform***' since all the numbers are almost the same.

b) For a sequence 1,2,1,2,1,100,1,1 we can say it is '***spiky***' since 100 is very large while others are almost the same and small.

c) For a sequence 1,10,5,9,2,12,3,4 we can say it is '_____'?

where all the numbers vary in a large range compared with (a) but not very large compared with (b).

Comment: In electronics and statistics it might be described as "noisy".  Then one can use several terms for measures of the randomness of the noise.

Comment: "Bursty" is another term of art for particular patterns of correlation in signals.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the sequence you gave has a generating function, it is a [random](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/random?s=ts) sequence.  If you wanted to specify that the numbers didn't exceed certain values you can say that the sequence is [bounded](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/bounded), say between 1 and 10.

I have never heard the term "spiky" used to talk about the sequence you posted.  When discussing data on a chart or graph, one could say there was a spike in X, or X spiked.

If you were discussing the three sequences, you could say "a exhibits uniformity, b random spikes, and c is random." (this assumes that the spikes in your sequence are random.)

Comment: +1. A *randomized list* or a *randomized set* is a frequent expression that I come across.

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Those options work also.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you're looking for a figurative term.

A **spike** is a sudden significant rise on a series of plotted values. A spike is brief, that is, the subsequent plotted value drops down. We wouldn't call a sudden rise to a high plateau a "spike". The series could be said to be **spiky** if it has a few, or more than a few, spikes.

If you wanted to say that there is a significant variation in the values of a series, but nothing that could be called a **spike**, you could say the series is **uneven**, which would imply that it is not *uniform*.

Comment: This raises an interesting question: How is she viewing the numbers--as a sequence or plotted on a graph?

Comment: I mention this because "uneven" makes sense when viewing the numbers on a graph but not so well as a sequence.

Comment: **spike** suggests something visual to me.

Answer (score 1):

At the risk of sounding facetious, **non-uniform**.

Mathematical language generally works in pairs: prime/non-prime, continuous/discontinuous*, where the first describes something that fits a rule, and the other something that doesn't. Where something is defined as "not fitting this rule", the word to describe it follows from that negation.

The reason for this is that it's obvious from the word where the definition comes from; I may not know what a non-homogeneous function is, but I know that if I look up a homogeneous function, it's whatever doesn't fit that definition. If it had another, unrelated name, like a "Convoluted Function", I may miss out of important information that is implied by the fact that it is not homogeneous... if that makes sense.

The point I'm getting at is that someone familiar with sequences and in particular uniform sequences will get what a non-uniform sequence means immediately, whereas using a different word may require them to figure out exactly what you mean.

If that's not what you're looking for, there are some other terms that might be of use:

- **Jagged** — more common in [Computer Science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jagged_array), it's often used to describe objects made up of pieces of variable length.
- **Variable** — that is to say, the contents of the sequence are of [High Variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance).

---

*In case anyone takes exception: Yes, discrete is often given as the opposite of continuous, but it has its own definition. A discontinuous function is defined as one that is *not continuous*.

Answer (score 0):

You're referring to data with high variability. [*Noisy*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal-to-noise_ratio) is often used within the signal processing fields (such as audio and video processing), to indicate data that have a higher variability than is otherwise expected within a given context.

*Random* has a different definition--a set of numbers chosen with equally and independently from the set of 1 and 2 would not be spiky, but would be random.

Answer (score 0):

They're not in common use, but I like "prickly" or "fuzzy".